# can i compile android project without eclipse?

Tags: android

Hello there is one question which comes in my mind from last 2 days. Can we compile our android project without Eclipse? If yes then what is alternatives? Please share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you are developing in a non-Eclipse environment, you can build your
>   project with the generated build.xml Ant file that is in the project
>   directory. The Ant file calls targets that automatically call the
>   build tools for you.

[Look at Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html) for more details.

```
cd /path/to/my/app
ant release
```

it will ask you every time for your private key to sign the app, it can be configured to auto-sign by editing "build.properties" file:

```
key.store=release.keystore
key.alias=release
key.store.password=my_key_password
key.alias.password=my_key_password
```

you can also investigate Android SDK, find the ANT build scripts it actually uses, and insert your custom obfuscator/optimizer call in middle of build process.

Comment: Yes, that is correct and some IDE's also provide a make build script. But, being too novice, I would also like to know if it is possible to compile without the aide of these files? Something like we can do with commandline java compilation?? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

one option is `ant`, and an extremely reduced tutorial goes like this:

first update your project with a proper build script and all the files that ant needs, you can do that with just one command, for example

```
android update project -p . -t android-10
```

this command has many options, feel free to browse for those options.

after that just do

```
ant debug
```

or

```
ant release
```

depending on what you want to produce, again, ant has other variations and you can easily discover them with the Android docs.

Answer (score 2):

For people that are not used to coding in java and want to use HTML/JavaScript and CSS to build native apps for android -- you can use PhoneGap -- you can upload your code in a zip and get an APK. Currently its in beta, and thats why free.

https://build.phonegap.com/

Other Phone OSes are also supported. Its pretty interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you just do not want to use Eclipse IDE you can choose other IDE like [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven with the maven android plugin http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/. Afterwards you can use any IDE that supports maven (NetBeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA).